# QQmlApplicationEngine and WindowFlags

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Since release Qt5.1, `QtQuick.Controls 1.0` module required `QQmlApplicationEngine`  to start.
That class automatically load qml-file and setup View.
But I can`t found how to apply`Qt::WindowFlags` to that view.
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the flags with the property `flags` like this for example:

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 640
    height: 480

    flags: Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.FramelessWindowHint

    Button {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    }
}
```

You can of course use `QtQuick 2.0` and the modules `Controls` and `Window` without having anything autoloading your QML files. I do it by using [QQuickView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquick/qquickview.html), specifically the method [setSource()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquick/qquickview.html#source-prop)